# colorbox move when scroll up and down

Tags: css, colorbox

In my colorbox code, this is the default CSS code:

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this case, the colorbox displays in the center of the page but does not move when scrolled up and down. However, when I change the code to this:

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the colorbox moves when scrolled up and down but is not displayed at the center of the page. How can I combine these effects?

Comment: this question has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 0):

Set the width, height and offset of the colorbox using something like:

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:9999;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 500px; //set the width
    height: 500px; // set the height
    margin-left: -250px; // negative offset to center the element
    margin-top: -250px // negative offset to center the element
}
```

Here, you are setting the position from the `top` and `left` to be `50%`, you are setting the `width` and `height` to be `500px`, and then offsetting the element by half it's width and height (since position starts from the top left corner) using negative margin

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hp4kxLz/)

Comment: nice but the top and the left of the popup do not appear

Comment: what do you mean don't appear?